# Send UDP messages to azure IoT in C#

Tags: c#, azure, udp, azure-iot-hub

I am working in Azure IoT hub,  Azure IoT Hub allows devices to use the following protocols (each of them based on TCP) for device-side communications:

MQTT (and MQTT over WebSockets)
AMQP (and AMQP over WebSockets)
HTTPS

But I want to send also UDP. So I follow the documents,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-visual-studio-develop-module

https://www.danielemaggio.eu/iot/udp-iot-edge/

Now the code is buildable, but the message not receiving . How can I solve the issue?

Comment: UDP does not guarantee that a message will be delivered, so if you are expecting to send 1 message and always receive that message, use TCP. What is your use case for UDP any ways?

Comment: udpPort = 1208;  UdpClient _udpClient = new UdpClient(udpPort);
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Be careful, as the Receive method will block until a datagram arrives from a remote host
                    Byte[] receiveBytes = _udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);   How can  I send messages to  this port?

Comment: I did not ask for your code, I asked what you are trying to achieve. And as already stated, UDP does not guarantee that a packet will arrive to wherever you are sending. So "Now the code is buildable, but the message not receiving" is to be expected. So, again, what are you trying to achieve with UDP? Do you have any reason to use UDP over TCP? What are those reasons?

Comment: it's requirement, just want to send UDP messages to IoT hub, so I trying to develop a sample code, with console application.

Comment: Ok, so please [edit] your question to include your example code of both sides of the communication. So of your app sending a UDP request and your app receiving. Also, try sending 100 packets and seeing how many arrive

Comment: I referred this code -https://www.danielemaggio.eu/iot/udp-iot-edge/

Comment: do you have a full IoT Edge solution up and running? From your question it sounds like you should start with a simple tutorial on how to build a custom module. Then go on from there with your UDP receiver